# Why can't gerne be used like 'like'

Tags: verb, usage

In English we say

> I like Coffee.

But I've never seen anyone saying

> Ich gerne Coffee.

Why is this incorrect?

Google translator gives translation as above English version.

Here am just considering the meaning *like* for *gerne*.

Comment: When Jews brought Yiddish to America they adapted "gleich" in the English sense of "like":  ich gleich coffee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Gerne" is an adverb, not a verb like "like." (The second like is a verb, the first is a modifier.) Gerne in this context means something like "gladly," as an adverb.

A correct construction is, Ich trinke gerne Kaffee. Roughly, "I drink coffee gladly," which can be translated idiomatically as "I like coffee."

Or even, "Ich habe Kaffee gern." This is roughly I "have" coffee gladly, or I have a liking for coffee.

Answer (score 4):

The verb "to like something" can be translated as »etwas mögen«:

> I **like** coffee.
>   Ich **mag** Kaffee.
>
> You will **like** this book. Read it!
>   Du wirst dieses Buch **mögen**. Lies es!
>
> Why did you kill Rocky? I **liked** him!
>   Warum hast du Rocky getötet? Ich **mochte** ihn.

---

The German adverb is hard to translate 1:1 into German, because it uses to appear in constructions, that are built different in Englisch.

> Möchten sie mehr Milch? Ich bringe Ihnen **gerne** welche.
>   Do you want more milk? I would be **pleased** to bring you some.
>
> Nein, du musst ihn nicht zwingen das Klo zu putzen. Er macht das wirklich **gerne**.
>   No, you don't need to force him to clean the toilet. He really does it **willingly**.
>
> Ich bin **gerne** mit Ihren Vorschlag einverstanden.
>   I am **happy** to agree with your proposal.